Cannot expose AMQP port of RabbitMQ pod from Openshift
I cannot expose AMQP port of RabbitMQ from OpenShift.
Which is the correct way to do it?
Here are the Helm templates:
kind: Route
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  name: rabbit-amqp
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    {{- include "app.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  host: "my-dns"
  port:
    targetPort: amqp
  wildcardPolicy: None
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: rabbit-amqp
    weight: 100

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: rabbit-amqp
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    {{- include "app.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5672
      targetPort: 5672
      name: amqp
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    {{- include "app.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4}}

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbit
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    {{- include "app.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "app.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        {{- include "app.labels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
          name:  rabbit
          env:
            - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER
              value: admin
            - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
              value: admin
          ports:
            - name: management
              containerPort: 15672
              protocol: TCP
            - name: amqp
              containerPort: 5672
              protocol: TCP
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30


I've tried with a Route mapped to a ClusterIP service on port 5672.
When I try to connect a client using the route (I'm on the same VPN), I see no logs from the container.
If I expose the port using kubectl portforward it works.
Command oc describe service rabbit-amqp -n dev  result:
Name:              rabbit-amqp
Namespace:         dev
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                   chart.name=rabbit
                   chart.version=0.0.1
                   name=rabbit
Annotations:       meta.helm.sh/release-name: rabbit
                   meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: dev
Selector:          name=rabbit
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                172.30.18.20
IPs:               172.30.18.20
Port:              amqp  5672/TCP
TargetPort:        5672/TCP
Endpoints:         172.31.11.186:5672
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>


Could you add a command result oc describe service rabbit-amqp -n dev? And please check that there are endpoints which are the Pod IP of RabbitMQ.

@hiroyukik command result added.
The Endpoint is the same assigned to service rabbit-management used to reach the port 15672 through route in order to access the management page.

Thank you for adding the result. The service seems to be ok. And I have one more question to you. Which protocol do you use to access RabbitMQ? Actually, OpenShift Router only support http/https with SNI based protocols. So that TCP protocol can not be transferred via the Router. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.16/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#nw-creating-a-route_route-configuration

@hiroyukik I use amqp protocol that is TCP based. You're right, we can't use the Router. Which is the proper way to expose this port to internet?

For TCP based protocol, OpenShift has two ways to export the Pod port, NodePort service and ExternalIP Service.
NodePort is a service exporse the pod port on OpenShift Nodes. You can access the ports with any Node IP address. On the other hand, External IP is a service expose the pod port with a VIP.
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.16/networking/configuring_ingress_cluster_traffic/configuring-ingress-cluster-traffic-nodeport.html
